# Fetch documents only when field values are specified

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need help with writing dynamic queries in mongo shell.

```
function(a, obj){
    db.courseContent.aggregate({$match: {Actor: a, ObjectId: obj}})
}
```

In the above function, I sometimes do not pass either `a` or `obj`.
I want the function to return documents of respective values.

> If both `a` & `obj` are passed it should return documents matching both `a`
>   & `obj` but not with matching either 'a' or 'obj'

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: You can check in your code for the parameters . If both are existing then use the $and condition or else the $or condition in your Mongodb query

Comment: I have only mentioned 2 fields as a sample. There are actually 8 fields, where I get the combination of two or three or just only one. In your case I may have to write many loops to identify the parameters. In short it is a search criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [$and operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) is what you need here, to match on *all* the submitted values; the query you want will look something like this:

```
{$match: {$and: [Actor: a, ObjectId: obj]}}
```

You can dynamically put together a query like that without too much bother, perhaps like this:

```
function(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h){
  var match = [];
  if (a) { match.push( {Alpha:   a} ); }
  if (b) { match.push( {Bravo:   b} ); }
  if (c) { match.push( {Charlie: c} ); }
  if (d) { match.push( {Delta:   d} ); }
  if (g) { match.push( {Echo:    e} ); }
  if (e) { match.push( {Foxtrot: f} ); }
  if (f) { match.push( {Gamma:   g} ); }
  if (h) { match.push( {Hotel:   h} ); }
  db.courseContent.aggregate([{$match: {$and: match}}])
}
```

Comment: Superb query, thank you Vince.
 You just missed one more '}'in the last aggregate statement.

Comment: Thanks @NNandu, I've fixed the missing '}' now.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
function(a, obj){
        if(a!='' && a!=undefined && obj!='' && obj!=undefined){

        db.courseContent.aggregate({$match:{$and:[{Actor: a, ObjectId: obj}]}});
        }
        else if(a!='' && a!=undefined){
        var obj={};
        var $match={};
        var finalobj={};
        finalobj["Actor"]=a;
        obj["$match"]=finalobj;
        db.courseContent.aggregate(obj);
        }
        else if(obj!='' && obj!=undefined){
        var obj={};
        var $match={};
        var finalobj={};
        finalobj["ObjectId"]=obj;
        obj["$match"]=finalobj;
        db.courseContent.aggregate(obj);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is working but in the original code, I have 8 fields which means I should write 36 if else conditions. Is there any other way to handle this?

Comment: Mongodb does not respond if you provide a undefined value to a column so may and plus you have to include all the fields when the value is existing that means you need to use an $and operator,so may b you ll have to handle those cases.

Comment: ok, thanks for the script. I found an issue with the script, when i do not pass value for 'obj' variable it gives me error:<br>
Error: Exceeded depth limit of 150 when converting js object to BSON. Do you have a cycle? :
DB.prototype._runCommandImpl@src/mongo/shell/db.js:114:13
DB.prototype.runCommand@src/mongo/shell/db.js:124:16
DB.prototype.runReadCommand@src/mongo/shell/db.js:109:13
DBCollection.prototype._dbReadCommand@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:127:12
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate/doAgg<@src/mongo/shell/collection.js

Comment: i have posted another answer have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Generic code which might work for you

```
function(valuearray,keyarray){
    var and={};
    and.$and=[];
     var obj={};
    for(var i=0;i<valuearray.length;i++){
     if(valuearray[i]!=undefined && valuearray[i]!=''){
       obj[keyarray[i]]=valuearray[i];
       and.$and.push(obj);
      } 
    }
    db.courseContent.aggregate({$match:and});
   }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time. This is more generic creating the string if missing and checking the collection but it is truncating the key array if not as large as valuearray and also not fetching all the docs. In contrast the previous answer was much closer but throws an error. Is it possible to fine tune the earlier answer.